# Socket io with nodejs custom socket ids

Tags: node.js, socket.io, chat

I'm making a chat app with socket.io, and I'd like to use my custom client id, instead of the default. Is there any ways of sending the custom identifier when connecting?  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple ways your server could send your own client id when a socket.io connection is made to the server:

1. You could set a cookie which the client would have access to.  The initial connection to socket.io is an HTTP request (all webSocket connections are initiated with an HTTP request) so you could set a cookie as part of that initial request.
2. After the server sees the incoming connection, you can coin the client id and just send it to the client as your own message.

Here's an example:

```
io.on('connection', function (socket) {
  // create the client id here
  // ...
  // send the id to the client
  socket.emit('setID', clientID);
});
```

The client would then listen for the `setID` message to get its ID.